# Teamcity 9 - Artifact dependencies parameters

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

My question is about the artifacts dependencies parameters.

I have different branches add same configurations running on these branches in projects. In some configurations I consume an artifact dependency specific to the branch. And I have different templates in the project that define this artifact dependency.

I would like to:
- Copy a project with all the configurations
- Define in one shot the artifact dependencies of all my copied configurations to get the artifact from the new branch. -> Possible if I can put a parameter in the grey section in next image.

[Artifact dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO2PF.png)

With that, I can change my parameter in the project parameters and all inner build configuration will get the correct artifact build.
Is there a solution for that?

Thanks.